# How do I get the base elements attribute in a Geb module

Tags: grails, groovy, module, geb

Given the HTML:
    fooLink

and the page object

```
class FooPage extend geb.Page {
    static content = {
        foo = { Module FooModule, $('.foo') }
    }
}
```

What is the correct implementation to get the @href element out of the module?

```
class FooModule extends geb.module {
    static content = { 
        smartField = { doSomethingSmartWith(?.@href) }
    }
}
```

I've tried, this, delegate, base, $ and @, none of them work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Derp, I found it immediately after posting the question.  $().

Here it is in case this helps someone:

```
class FooModule extends geb.module {
    static content = { 
        smartField = { doSomethingSmartWith($().@href) }
    }
}
```