# How can I access the root element of a geb module

Tags: jquery, geb

I want to test that a double click on a list item in my page opens the corresponding item for editing.

Here's the structure of my page:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item" ondblclick="jQuery(this).find('.edit-button').click();">
    ...some content...
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have the following geb page defining the items using a geb `moduleList` of `ListItem` modules:

```
class ListPage extends Page {
  static content = {
    items { moduleList ListItem, $("li.item") }
  }
  ...
}
```

In the `ListItem` module I want to access the root `li` element to trigger the double click on it.

How can I access the `li` in the `ListItem` module?

The correct jQuery selector would probably be `$(this)` but in the module `this` point to the module instance and not to the root element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After posting my question I recognized a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467323/how-do-i-get-the-base-elements-attribute-in-a-geb-module?rq=1) providing the answer.

`$()` refers to the root element of a geb module.